# Can't Play .wav file with winsound module?

Tags: python, wav

I am trying to play a .wav file like this:

```
import winsound
winsound.PlaySound('test.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

When the script is ran there are no errors but a default windows alert sound is played instead of the test.wav file.

Comment: I don't know about `winsound`, but you might want to try the [sounddevice](http://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/) module instead.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the wav file you are trying to play is in the same folder as the py script is in. Otherwise you have to provide a correct relative path to the file or it won't find it.
Example:

```
import winsound
import sys

winsound.PlaySound(Test.wav,winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

With SND_ASYNC the windows beep shouldn't play and your wav file should play.

Answer (score 0):

try
'from winsound import *'
that'll work

Answer (score -1):

**put your wav file same folder as the py script is in**

```
winsound.PlaySound('test.wav', winsound.SND_FILENAME)
```

this line of code will work. It's working for me.